# PHP Regex preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a large text file that i need to remove a certain piece of information from, but i am still learning regular expressions and need some help with the search string statement.

Below is an example of the data i am trying to extract:

```
"id": "12345"  (good)
"id": "a123"   (bad)
```

The part i am having trouble with, is that i want to grab the first example, which has ONLY numbers as the value for ID. If there is a letter within the ID, i do not want to grab it. The ID numbers also differ in length, but the format is consistent:

```
"id": "number_here"
```

I have the following code but it does not seem to work for what i want to do:

```
preg_match_all("/\"id\"\:\s\"[0-9]\"/", $input_file)
```

Comment: Does this text file have any particular structure?  It looks like it could be JSON

Answer (score 4):

Your regex is good (if a bit heavy on backslashes), except for one fatal flaw: You are only searching for a single digit.

```
preg_match_all('/"id": "[0-9]+"/', $input_file, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: worked like a charm! thank you very much!!! I was under the impression that all special chars had to be escaped.

Comment: @user3569450 Heh, well there's certainly no *harm* in escaping things that don't really need it, but it's just a lot more readable to do this ;)

Answer (score 2):

- You don't need to escape many characters in yiur regex
- Use single quotes for regex
- Make sure to use quantifier `+` to match 1 or more digits after `"id":`

You can use:

```
preg_match_all('/"id" *: *"[0-9]+"/', $input_string, $matches) ;
```